# Where to buy bar end shifters

Tags: shifter, shopping

I would really like to pickup a pair of bar end shifters but none of my local bike shops are able to get any for me.  My local bike dump laughed in my face when I asked them where I should/could find them.

Where online could I get some bar end shifters for a reasonable price?  (Bonus points for cheap shipping to/in Canada).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first place I look for 'unusual' parts is [Loose Screws](http://www.loosescrews.com). They have [Ultegra and Dura Ace bar end shifters available](http://www.loosescrews.com/index.cgi?c=Shifter&sc=Road%20Shifters&tc=Index&id=379563220638).

My second source is Rivendell Bicycle Works - They have a [couple of different](http://www.rivbike.com/products/list/shifters_and_derailers) options.

Not sure what you consider a reasonable price, but $100 US seems to be the ballpark for new shifters.

Finally - you can always try eBay for used parts, but that is hit and miss for both quality and selection when dealing with more obscure parts like these.

Answer (score 2):

The local bike shop sometimes need a bit of help when you get a 'newbie' member of staff. Shimano still make bar end shifters, if you provide the LBS with the part number then they can get them very quickly for you from the people that supply them with all the other Shimano stuff.

- Dura-Ace SL-BS77 - 8/9 speed
- Dura-Ace SL-BS77 - 10 speed
- Ultegra SL-BS64 - 8 speed
- SRAM TT900 - 10 speed
- Campagnolo (Various) - 10/11 speed, designed for triathlon aero bars
- Other TT specific shifters that are not necessarily indexed

Answer (score 2):

[ProBikeKit](http://www.probikekit.com/us/components/bicycle-gear-levers.html) has Shimano and Campy barcons and free shipping. The barcons they have are not cheap. So it goes.

Rivendell (op cit) also sells adaptors that let you mount downtube shifters as barcons. This might let you frankenbike something together more cheaply.